# Launch multiple times the same instance Amazon Sagemaker Studio

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

On Amazon Sagemaker Studio, I would like to be able to launch multiple time the same instance.

So far, I can start only one "ml.t3.medium" instance for example; I would like to launch two separate instance of "ml.t3.medium" in the same jupyterlab. Is it possible?

Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create multiple instances of the same type in SageMaker Studio. However, each instance can run multiple apps and notebooks.
Can you share your requirements for needing multiple instances of the same size?

I work for AWS and my opinions are my own.

Comment: Is it not trivial? Willing to have multiple instances of the same machine increase the ability to run in parallel on different machines?